# Gem devise getting started?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using this tutorial
https://launchschool.com/blog/how-to-use-devise-in-rails-for-authentication
 But i am a little bit confused.
I want to make simple app to see how devise works
So far I did this:
Added devise gem. then ran

```
rails generate devise:install     # Creates config file, etc.
rails generate devise user        # Create model class, routes, etc.
rake db:migrate                   # Create user table
rails generate devise:views users # Creates (minimal) views
```

My routes.rb file has `devise_for :users`
What are my next steps?
If I go to `http://localhost:3000/users/signin` or `http://localhost:3000/signin` It says no routes are defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default signin and sign out links are,

http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in

and

http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out

To see what your current routes are, try following in console,

> rake routes

To generate signout link in view, add following,

```
<%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: okay, where is sign out path?  I get an error: `No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"` but I have this line: `destroy_user_session_path DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format) devise/sessions#destroy`

How do i sign out?

Comment: Use this in your view to add a sign_out link,
<%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>

Comment: Okay thanks for this and I have last question: as far as I understand, If I want to add admin user I need manually create user and set `user.admin = true`in rake db:populate task?

Comment: If you have a admin flag then yes. Refer this for more,
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role